# How to add ALL user input to ArrayList instead of every other input?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, user-input

Title. I'm really just practicing but I'm trying to take user inputed names, add them to an array list, and then print them out at the end. My problem is that it's whenever strings are entered, it's only adding every other name to the arraylist.

```
public class test {
static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String namesIn = "";
    while (true){
        namesIn = scan.nextLine();
        if (namesIn.isEmpty()){
            break;
        }
        else {
            names.add(namesIn);
            System.out.println("name added");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This code works fine, you must not be running this particular update. Recompile, rerun.

Comment: Agreed, this code works as you described, except for the part about printing the values in the array list at the end.